# What are the steps to upgrade node packages in Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm

I have upgraded my Laravel application from 5.5 to 6 and now I want to upgrade all JS packages (Vue.js, jquery, lodash etc.)
I can make that change in package.json but can you tell me the steps esp. for Laravel.
Am I suppose to use Laravel Mix(Webpack)?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to modify the `package.json`. You can do it all with command.

```sh
// this is checking what packages are outdated.
npm outdated
```

```sh
// this is updating all the packages.
npm update
```

And it's pretty much done.

If there is a major version change which may cause breaking changes, by the laravel default settings `npm update` will not update to the latest version, you can run this:

```sh
// npm install yourPackage@latest
// for example if it's vue
npm install vue@latest --save
```

And it's all done.